Energy Distribution after 3D Elastic Collision between Two Atoms
I'm conducting research on elastic collisions of atoms, and I've encountered an interesting question regarding the energy distribution after a 3D collision between two atoms.
Consider two atoms, both with the same initial speed, $v_1 = v_2 = 1$ (for simplicity). The directions of their velocities are random. Assume that an elastic collision is guaranteed to happen in 3D space. We work in the lab frame, and for simplicity, we define the initial direction of atom 1’s velocity along the z-axis. When the collision occurs, atom 2 is at $(0, 0, 0)$ with velocity components as $(v_2 \cos(\theta_2) \sin(\phi_2), v_2 \cos(\theta_2) \sin(\phi_2), v_2 \cos(\phi_2))$, while atom 1 is located at $(\cos(\theta_1) r_1, \sin(\theta_1) r_1, -\sqrt{1-(r_1 / R)^2})$ with velocity $(0, 0, v_1)$.
To introduce randomness, I sample $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ from $2\pi \times \text{rand}(0,1)$, $r_1$ from $\sqrt{R^2 \times \text{rand}(0,1)}$ and $\phi_2$ from $\arccos(1 - 2\times\text{rand(0,1)})$. This means the velocity direction of atom 2 is sampled from the surface of a unit sphere, and the x-y position of atom 1 is sampled from the area of a unit circle.
I simulate the collision 10000000 times and observe a distribution for the final kinetic energy ($\propto v_1^{'2}$).
My question is: Does there exist a closed-form expression for this intriguing energy distribution?


I think you should properly study the relevant physics. It is actually completely solvable in the centre-of-momentum frame of reference. That is, you should be able to get an analytic expression for the entire system, and thus you should be able to plot this energy distribution's analytical expression, and then compare it with your simulation.
